# Printing information from arrays, without using duplicate values

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program that takes in Olympic medals data, and prints out various information.  This particular part is proving a bit difficult in terms of logic and structure.  I am trying to take a `String array` and an `int array` (which were both created in the main method), pass them to a new method, and print out information regarding them.

My arrays are as follows (please note that String array is in alphabetical order):

```
        String[] country = {"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Canada", "China", "Italy", "Mexico"};
        int[] totalMedals = {1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2};
```

I would like to print out to be as follows:

```
Afghanistan, 3 medal(s)
Canada, 1 medal(s)
China, 1 medal(s)
Italy, 3 medal(s)
Mexico, 2 medal(s)
```

I can easily write the program that lists out in this format, but countries that appear more than once (in this sample example...Afghanistan) is listed as many times as it comes up in the array.  As written, my output is:

```
Afghanistan, 1 medal(s)
Afghanistan, 2 medal(s)
Canada, 1 medal(s)
China, 1 medal(s)
Italy, 3 medal(s)
Mexico, 2 medal(s)
```

Afghanistan is listed twice (to give a big of context, this is a smaller part of the program.  The program actually houses athletes names as well, but that is taken care of in different methods).

Can anyone provide me a bit of help regarding the best way to print out my desired output?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] country = {"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Canada", "China", "Italy", "Mexico"};
    int[] totalMedals = {1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2};

    listCountryMedals(country, totalMedals);

}

    //List the grand total of medals for each country...display name only once
public static void listCountryMedals(String[] country, int[] totalMedals) {

    for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(country[i] + ", " + totalMedals[i] + " medal(s)");            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to use arrays and loops you can do the following:

```
public static void listCountryMedals(String[] country, int[] totalMedals) {
  boolean[]seen = new boolean[country.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < country.length - 1; i++) {
      int medals = totalMedals[i];
      if (!seen[i]) {
          for(int j = i + 1; j < country.length; j++) {
             if (country[i].equals(country[j])) {
                 medals += totalMedals[j];
                 seen[j] = true; //I already took this country
             }
          }
          System.out.println(country[i] + ", " + medals + " medal(s)");
      }
      seen[i] = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Contrary to all the Map-based answers (of complexity O(n)), the complexity of this answer is O(n²). This may be significant with bigger lists.

Comment: Ooh, I don't like this.  Why not just use some kind of `Set` for the seen countries, instead of the `boolean[]`?  Then you won't need that inner loop and all those extra comparisons.

Comment: I completely agree that this solution is inefficient as mentioned by @FlorentBayle, and surely a set or a HashMap is the more elegant solution. However, I believe the person who asked the question is not familiar yet with objects and classes but he knows only about methods and the main() as a starting point for a program. He is also very bright which is why I believe he is trying extra things. This comes from my experience of teaching, very commonly I find such questions. So I chose an answer that would make sense to the person posing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public static void listCountryMedals(String[] country, int[] totalMedals)
    {
        Map<String, Integer> countryMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++)
        {
            Integer medals = countryMap.get(country[i]);
            Integer sum = (medals == null) ? totalMedals[i] : (totalMedals[i] + medals);
            countryMap.put(country[i], sum);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> countryMedals : countryMap.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(countryMedals.getKey() + ", " + countryMedals.getValue() + " medal(s)");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could simplify this slightly by doing `countryMap.get(country[i]);` before the `if` statement, assigning it to an `Integer` and either changing the `if` condition to `if (medals != null)` or replacing it with a ternary operator.

Comment: No, not like that!  What you did isn't what I meant at all; and I think it's slightly more complicated now.  Umm, do you mind if I edit your answer to demonstrate what I had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Change your method as follows.

```
public static void listCountryMedals(String[] country, int[] totalMedals) {

     //Map to hold the conuntry anme and medal count pair
     Map<String,Integer> countryNameToMedalCountMap= new HashMap<String,Integer>();

      for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {           
         if(countryNameToMedalCountMap.get(country[i]) == null) {
             countryNameToMedalCountMap.put(country[i],totalMedals[i]);
         } else {
             int count = map.get(country[i]);
             countryNameToMedalCountMap.put(country[i],count+totalMedals[i];
        }
     }

      //Print the map
      for(String counrty : countryNameToMedalCountMap.keySet()) {
          System.out.println(country+" "+ countryNameToMedalCountMap.get(country)+" medal(s).");
      }
}
```

Note : With this approach, Country names will be case sensitive. You have to device some mechanism if you want case insensitive. Like converting the map keys always to the lower case and doing same while looking up

Answer (score 0):

You should take an object-orientated approach:

```
public class Country {

    private String name;
    private int medals;

    //getters/setters/constructors

}
```

Then it becomes easy:

```
List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

//when you want to reference/print those:
for (Country c : countries) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s, %d medals(s)", c.getName(), c.getMedals()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `LinkedHashMap` to sum the medals by country:

```
//List the grand total of medals for each country...display name only once
public static void listCountryMedals(String[] country, int[] totalMedals) {
    final Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();


    for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
        if (!map.containsKey(country[i]))
            map.put(country[i], 0);
        map.put(country[i], map.get(country[i]) + totalMedals[i]); 
    }

    for (final Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + " medal(s)");           
    }
}
```

Contrary to the classical `HashMap`, the `LinkedHashMap` will preserve the key order when iterating. It seems that your countries are currently sorted, so you may want to keep them in this order when you print them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to store these information, country as key and medal count as value.

```
public static void listCountryMedals(String[] country, int[] totalMedals) 
{
    Map<String, Integer> countryMedalMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) 
    {
        String countryName = country[i];
        /**
         * If the country is already in the map, get the number of medal and add it up with value 
         * from totalMedals array for that country. Then put it back to map with the new medal count.
         */
        if(countryMedalMap.containsKey(countryName))
        {
            int medalCount = countryMedalMap.get(countryName) + totalMedals[i];
            countryMedalMap.put(countryName, medalCount);
        }
        /**
         * If the country is not in the map, put it into map with its medal count.
         */
        else
        {
            countryMedalMap.put(countryName, totalMedals[i]);
        }
    }

    printMap(countryMedalMap);
}

/**
 * Print the map
 * 
 * @param map
 */
public static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> map)
{
    for (String countryName : map.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s, %s medal(s)", countryName, map.get(countryName)));
    }
}
```